# Javascript error on different versions of firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, firefox

I wondered if anyone with some JavaScript experience may have a way to resolve my issue!

I'm using version 5 of firefox (using front motion if that makes a difference), yes I know this is out of date by quite a way but it's down to corporate policy!

Anyway in version 5 of Firefox my function fires and works correctly, however in v14 and v15 it gives me an error saying that the function I'm using is not a function. The line in question is the one that starts var $tabs.

Any ideas? Thanks in advance

```
$(function() {
    if ($('.ui-tabs-panel').length > 0) {        
        var $tabs = $('#tabs').tabs();

        $(".ui-tabs-panel").each(function(i) {        

            var totalSize = $(".ui-tabs-panel").size() - 1;
            if (i != totalSize) {
                next = i + 2;
                $(this).append("<a href='#' class='next-tab mover' rel='" + next + "'>Next Page &#187;</a>");
                $('.toggle').hide();
            }
            if (i != 0) {
                prev = i;
                $(this).append("<a href='#' class='prev-tab mover' rel='" + prev + "'>&#171; Prev Page</a>");
                $('.toggle').hide();
            }
        });

        $('.next-tab, .prev-tab').click(function() {
            $tabs.tabs('select', $(this).attr("rel"));
            return false;
        });
    }
});​
```

Comment: Where does the console say the problem is?

Comment: I'm using jquery so the $ is needed. The error states the 3rd line of javascript

Comment: Are you sure the tabs JavaScript is loaded? Do you see it loaded under the scripts tab in your debugger?

Comment: You are doing a $tabs = $('#tabs').tabs() try doing $tabs = $('#tabs')  in the listener for .prev-tab, it would resolve to $('#tabs').tabs().tabs('select'...) in your code

Comment: Thanks Karthikr, I just tried this, it removes the error for the function not being recognised. However the actual script no longer functions! :(

Comment: be sure you put correctly the script src of jquery ui. Some doublequote missed or something similar. Analyze it with firebug if jquery-ui is correctly loaded in FF5.